# Linearly independent vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prove if $r_1 \neq r_2$ the vectors (functions):

$$ \bar{v_1}=e^{r_1t}, \bar{v_2}=e^{r_2t}$$

are *linearly independent* in the continuous functions space in $-\infty<t<\infty$

I've tried to prove this supposing they are linearly dependent and I obtained $c_1=-c_2e^{t(r_2-r_1)}$ from this I don't know how to follow. Can anyone help me with a hint? Thanks.

Comment: Put in $t = 1$ and $t = -1$.

Comment: Thanks!, i obtained, $r_1=r_2$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$c_1=-c_2e^{t(r_2-r_1)}$ is an *equality of functions*, and not an equation. This means that no matter what $t$ you insert / evaluate at, the right hand side becomes the same thing, namely $c_1$. If it becomes the same thing no matter what $t$ is, what possible value could $r_2-r_1$ have?

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? What can I do better?

Comment: Thanks!, i obtained, $ r_1=r_2$ a contradiction. 
By the way, I do not vote negative to you answer.

Comment: @P3peM4th. That's what you're supposed to obtain, so that's good. And I didn't think it was you (I don't think you can...), it's just that some people downvote without explaining, which doesn't tell me what's wrong, so I can't fix it. That means the downvote doesn't help anyone at all.

Comment: yes! you are right i can't, :P, and i agree about the downvote without explaining it's inservible,  thanks for the help!